# Empty array - Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I must get a value in a json data like in following link: 
[Value in json data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxtFq.png) (sorry because I can't emb image).
I need to get value of **"DT sau CK"** and I see that it's value is an **empty array [ ]**. My function is:

```js
function test () {
  api_url = 'https://my url....'
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(api_url);  
  var data = JSON.parse(result);
  var dtt = data['chart']['data'][2]['value'];
  if (dtt == false || dtt.length == 0) {
    dtt = 0;
  } else {
    dtt = data['chart']['data'][2]['value'];
  }
  return Number(dtt)
}
```

My if "dtt.length == 0" for an emty array.
I want it to give me value/number 0 but it always return another number 157548000, something like that, maybe by api_url/server. But i want to get a number "0" result as i saw  an empty array.
Can anyone help me, thanks a lot and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You should add a sample of `result` to your question. The error must lie in the datastructure or how you access it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add this to replace empty arrays with '0':

```
chart.data.forEach(function (item) {
 if (item.value.length===0) {
   item.value=0;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue recently, the solution is to just delete empty/extra columns.